# Check Array Object as Part of WHERE Clause

Tags: postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I am using postgres 9.4 and the jsonb type. I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE jsonb_test (iid serial NOT NULL, data jsonb)
```

And the following json data in that table:

```
{"date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "items": [{"name": "bottles", "price": 12}, {"name": "caps", "price": 20}], "customer": {"name": "Customer 1", "email": "customer1@gmail.com"}}
{"date": "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", "items": [{"name": "bottles", "price": 1}, {"name": "caps", "price": 50}], "customer": {"name": "Customer 2", "email": "customer2@gmail.com"}}
```

What I would like to do is to get all rows that have an item with a price greater than 30. In this case that would return the Customer 2 row.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_test WHERE jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_extract_path(data, 'items')) #> '{price}' > '0'
```

But this fails with the error `ERROR: argument of WHERE must not return a set`

Can anyone tell me how to do this? Is is possible to do this for an arbitrary level of nesting?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read [Why can't I query directly on jsonb_array_elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687945/why-cant-i-query-directly-on-jsonb-array-elements)

Comment: @abarisone I did see that, what wasn't clear to me is how to do greater than/less than operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

`SELECT * FROM jsonb_test, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_test.data->'items') AS a WHERE (a->>'price') > '0'`

Comment: This works and as the added benefit of providing the items elements themselves. I wonder though, can this be nested? If I had an array of objects that also had an array of object how would those be queried?

Comment: @shortspider try this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571338/postgres-jsonb-query-on-nested-object

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this :

```
SELECT * FROM json_test WHERE jsonb_test.data #> '{items,price}' > '30';
```

What I am trying to do is: Give me objects where element items has a child object that has element price equal to the integer '1'.

checkout some examples here : http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/

Comment: This returns no results for me, even if I change the comparison to  > '0'

Comment: i have a typo mistake jsonb_test after FROM. try and see

Comment: I did and still nothing. Here's the query: `SELECT * FROM jsonb_test WHERE jsonb_test.data #> '{items,price}' > '0';`